# Is it possible to override scope of a dependency managed defaultly through imported BOM without overriding version?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am not sure if that is a bug or a feature, but I am trying to override only the scope, but not version, of a dependency managed in an imported BOM, within dependencyManagement section. If I do that, the version is unknown but I am not sure if that is on purpose or I have problems in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven documentation states that this is an intent of [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> Dependency scope is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency,
>   and also to affect the classpath used for various build tasks.

So, yes - it should be possible to override the scope. However, how exactly overriding affects the classpath, depends on initial scope value and its final value.

Also, if you're overriding the scope of the dependency from BOM, you need to do it in the `<dependencies>` and not in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

`<dependencyManagement>` is used to define dependencies versions, so the only suitable scope in this section is `import` for BOMs. However, there is an exception for scope `provided`: [`provided` specified in `<dependencyManagement>` will override defined scope in `<dependencies>` section](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/DependencyManagement-to-force-scope-td112273.html).

Comment: But I think the question is whether attributes follow  fallback independently or it's atomicaly an either-or

Comment: @Whimusical I updated the answer, assuming I understood the question:) Can you please give a bit more information? Specifically: what was original scope of the dependency and to what value did you change it? Also, it will help to understand your specific case, if you updated the question with some simplified version of `pom.xml` before and after change.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering.. What I mean is if there is some way to change the scope from a dependency that comes from imported BOM without having to override the whole definition of that dependency (including the version ) in your <dependencies> section

Comment: @Whimusical Because of maven dependency resolution strategy, **there is no way to override only the scope**. Basically, **you should give full dependency definition** (including version).